# Problem In Implementing Nested Routing In Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I know there are too many similar questions and I tried them but none of them fixed my problem. The structure of my routes is like:

```
Layout
  /Settings Route
     UserSettings [Container]
        UserSettings [Component]
  /Private Route x
  /Private Route y
  /Private Route z
  /Private Route a
```

I have a layout which consists of all the private routes. One of the routes is settings route.
I want my settings routes to look like facebooks settings page, i.e, have a sidebar with different links which open as the sub-routes of settings, like:

```
localhost:3000/settings/**settings1**
localhost:3000/settings/**settings2**
localhost:3000/settings/**settings3**
localhost:3000/settings/**settings4**
```

Where settings1-2-3-4 is a sub-route, and changes.
I tried putting the sidebars and link's with NavLinks in UserSettings [component]

```
<Route path={`${path}/:id`} component={UserSettings[Component]} />
```

The links, when clicked go to the specified url i.e,**localhost:3000/settings/profile**, but the page is just blank.

NOTE: The links and sidebar show up in **localhost:3000/settings/**

But it is not working. Please tell me how to do it, I have tried each and every method present.

My code:

```
//Layout.js


 //secured routes
      const PrivateRoutes = ({ component, path, isUserLogged }) => {
          return isUserLogged ? (
              <Route
                  exact
                  path={path}
                  render={() => <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>{component}</Suspense>}
              />
          ) : (
              <Redirect exact to="/auth" />
          );
      };
```

---

```
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoutes
                path="/user"
                component={<UserProfiles />}
                isUserLogged={this.props.isUserLogged}
            />
            <PrivateRoutes
                path="/settings/"
                component={<UserSettings />}
                isUserLogged={this.props.isUserLogged}
            />

            <PrivateRoutes
                path="/"
                component={<Posts showMoreOptions={this.showPopupOptionsHandler} />}
                isUserLogged={this.props.isUserLogged}
            />
        </Switch>
```

---

//UserSettings.js[Component]

```
const EditProfileBasicInfo = (props) => {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

    return (
        <div className={style.userData}>
            <h3>Your Details</h3>

            <FilePond
                className={style.Filepond}
                allowMultiple={false}
                onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
                    setFiles({ files: fileItems.map((fileItem) => fileItem.file) });
                }}
                imagePreviewHeight={50}
                imageCropAspectRatio="1:1"
                // imageResizeTargetWidth={200}
                imageResizeTargetHeight={100}
                stylePanelLayout="compact circle"
                styleLoadIndicatorPosition="top center"
                // styleButtonRemoveItemPosition="center bottom"
                maxFiles={1}
                allowImagePreview={true}
                server="./"
            />

            <form onSubmit={props.submit}>
                <div className={style.Inline}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        id="firstName"
                        value={props.info.firstName}
                        onChange={(event) => props.changed(event)}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="lastName"
                        placeholder="Last Name"
                        value={props.info.lastName}
                        onChange={(event) => props.changed(event)}
                    />
                </div>

                <textarea
                    placeholder="Bio"
                    rows="4"
                    id="bio"
                    value={props.info.bio}
                    onChange={(event) => props.changed(event)}
                />

                <input
                    type="Email"
                    id="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={props.info.email}
                    disabled
                />

                <button onClick={props.submit}>Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

const SidebarLinks = ({ url, to, name }) => {
    return (
        <NavLink exact to={`${url}${to}`}>
            <li>
                <button>{name}</button>
            </li>
        </NavLink>
    );
};

const UserData = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const currentUrl = props.match.url;
    return (
        <Grid container direction="row" className={style.UserData_MainWrapper}>
            <Grid item xs={2}>
                <ul className={style.OptionButtons}>
                    <SidebarLinks to="profile" name="Profile" url={currentUrl} />
                    <SidebarLinks to="privacy" name="Privacy" url={currentUrl} />
                    <SidebarLinks to="security" name="Security" />
                    <SidebarLinks to="logout" name="Logout" />
                </ul>
            </Grid>

            <Grid xs={10} item>
                <Route
                    to={`${props.match.url}/:settingType`}
                    render={() => <EditProfileBasicInfo {...props} />}
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};
```

---

// UserSettings.js [Container] --> UserData is basically UserSettings Components
// I Am to rename it later.

```
const info = {
            email: emailVal,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            bio: bio,
        }

        return (
            <div className={style.CompleteUserData_MainWrapper}>
                <UserData
                    submit={this.onSubmitHandler}
                    info={info}
                    changed={this.onChangeHandeler}
                />
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Thanks for including details about your route structure and issue, but without a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example there isn't much advice or assistance to offer. Can you update your question to include the router component(s) and your `UserSettings` components? `react-router-dom` has some subtleties to get acquainted with.

Comment: Sorry, added the code!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the exact prop from the settings Private Route

```
    //Layout.js


 //secured routes
      const PrivateRoutes = ({ component, path, isUserLogged }) => {
          return isUserLogged ? (
              <Route
                 // exact   ---> This one. It stopped my routes from being displayed
                  path={path}
                  render={() => <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>{component}</Suspense>}
              />
          ) : (
              <Redirect exact to="/auth" />
          );
      };

---

And changing the below code:

    const SidebarLinks = ({ url, to, name }) => {
    return (
        <NavLink exact to={`${url}${to}`}>
            <li>
                <button>{name}</button>
            </li>
        </NavLink>
    );
};

const UserData = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const {path, url} = useRouteMatch(); ----> //import use route match
    return (
        <Grid container direction="row" className={style.UserData_MainWrapper}>
            <Grid item xs={2}>
                <ul className={style.OptionButtons}>
                    <SidebarLinks to="/profile" name="Profile" url={url} />  //Here
                    <SidebarLinks to="/privacy" name="Privacy" url={url} />  //Here
                    <SidebarLinks to="/security" name="Security" />
                    <SidebarLinks to="/logout" name="Logout" />
                </ul>
            </Grid>

            <Grid xs={10} item>
               <Switch>
               <Route path={path} exact />
                <Route
                    to={`${path}/profile`}
                    render={() => <EditProfileBasicInfo {...props} />}
                /> 
              </Switch>
            </Grid>
```